# Will it Work?.. Download querry for ipod

Tags: ipod, apple-id

I have an ipod and have two accounts with Apple. I was wondering if I started to download an app with one of my accounts and then  logged out of that account and used the other one, would the download still continue?

Comment: Sounds like something you could try. Please report back the results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once you have authenticated with Apple the download will continue just fine even if you log out while it is running.